# Как создать виртуальный audio device в Linux

Tags: linux, аудио, virtual, raspbian, alsa

Проблема такова:

Есть raspberry pi 3 c Raspbian на борту. Звук выводится в ALSA. Установлен консольный sip-клиент Baresip. При звонке туда, как и полагается - на динамики выводится звук с микрофона звонящего. Мне собственно нужно сделать так чтобы не выводился, и выводился по требованию(есть самописный демон на ноде). В функциях sip-клиента такого не нашел, но нашел в конфиге:

```
audio_player            alsa,default
audio_source            alsa,default
audio_alert             alsa,default
```

Полностью приглушить звук во всей системе не вариант, так как в фоне может играть что-то с аудиоплеера.

Comment: Вам вероятно нужен пакет типа PulseAudio, ну или еще вариант найти linux аналаг virtual cabel.

Comment: вы же как-то управляете sip-клиентом? так пошлите ему [команду mute](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip/wiki/Using-Baresip:-Basic-Commands#user-content-muteunmute)

Comment: mute выключит микрофон, а нужно выключить вывод на динамик